# How to draw an arc between edges connecting child nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have the following code to generate a couple of trees. How do I draw arcs between the edges (marked in red in the figure)?

```
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node {Goto(P$_A$)} [grow'=up]
child {node { Say(A,P$_A$)}}
child {node {IsTrue(A)}
};
\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
\node {Goto(P$_B$)} [grow'=up]
child { node [left=0cm]{ Goto(P$_B$)}
    child {node (sayb) { Say(B,P$_B$)}}
    child {node (istrueb) {IsTrue(B)}}
}
child {node [right=0cm]{ Goto(P$_B$)}
    child {node { Say(C,P$_B$)}}
    child {node {IsTrue(C)}}
};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be there are easier solutions but next one works. It draws a circle with center on parent anchor which is clipped inside a triangle with vertices in parent anchor and child centers.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newcommand\myarc[4]{\begin{scope}[very thick,red]
    \clip (#1)--(#2)--(#3)--cycle;
    \draw (#1) circle (#4);\end{scope}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (rootA) {Goto(P$_A$)} [grow'=up,parent anchor=north]
child {node { Say(A,P$_A$)}}
child {node {IsTrue(A)}
};

\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
\node (rootB) {Goto(P$_B$)} [grow'=up, parent anchor=north]
child { node [left=0cm]{ Goto(P$_B$)}
    child {node (sayb) { Say(B,P$_B$)}}
    child {node (istrueb) {IsTrue(B)}}
}
child {node [right=0cm]{ Goto(P$_B$)}
    child {node { Say(C,P$_B$)}}
    child {node {IsTrue(C)}}
};

\end{scope}

\myarc{rootA.north}{rootA-1.center}{rootA-2.center}{5mm}
\myarc{rootB.north}{rootB-1.center}{rootB-2.center}{6mm}
\myarc{rootB-1.north}{sayb.center}{istrueb.center}{5mm}
\myarc{rootB-2.north}{rootB-2-1.center}{rootB-2-2.center}{5mm}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update*

If you uses `TikZ 3.0` you can use `angles` library which defines a `pic angle`

> **Pic type** `angle=<A>--<B>--<C>`
>
> This pic adds a drawing of an angle to
>   the current path. This “drawing of an angle” consist of a “sector” or
>   “wedge” or “slice” whose pointed end is at point  and whose
>   straight sides lie on the lines form  to  and from  to .
>   [...]
>   The three points `<A>`, `<B>`, and `<C>` must be the names of nodes or coordinates; you 
>   cannot use direct coordinates like “(1,1)” here.

Last sentence creates a little problem because is not possible to use `rootA.north` as one of three point, it's necessary to convert it into a `coordinate`. It accepts `rootA` which means `rootA.center`.

Code with `angles` is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (rootA) {Goto(P$_A$)} [grow'=up]
child {node { Say(A,P$_A$)}}
child {node {IsTrue(A)}
};

\draw pic[draw, red, thick, angle radius=8mm] {angle=rootA-2--rootA--rootA-1};

\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
\node (rootB) {Goto(P$_B$)} [grow'=up, parent anchor=north]
child { node [left=0cm]{ Goto(P$_B$)}
    child {node (sayb) { Say(B,P$_B$)}}
    child {node (istrueb) {IsTrue(B)}}
}
child {node [right=0cm]{ Goto(P$_B$)}
    child {node { Say(C,P$_B$)}}
    child {node {IsTrue(C)}}
};

\end{scope}

\draw (rootB.north) coordinate (A) 
      pic[draw, red, thick, angle radius=3mm] 
      {angle=rootB-2--A--rootB-1};

\draw (rootB-1.north) coordinate (A) 
      pic[draw, red, thick, angle radius=3mm] 
      {angle=istrueb--A--sayb};

\draw (rootB-2.north) coordinate (A) 
      pic[draw, blue, very thick, angle radius=3mm] 
      {angle=rootB-2-2--A--rootB-2-1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is one possible solution. Since there were no sibling distance information, this solution assumes its own. Basically, internal names are given for each node and `calc` is used to determine the starting and ending points via ($(name1)!0.5!(name2)$), then draw the arc by, for example,

```
\draw ($(o)!0.5!(A)$) to[bend left=30]  ($(o)!0.5!(B)$);
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=2cm, 
                    level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
                    level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
]
\node (o) {Goto(P$_A$)} [grow'=up]
child {node (A) {Say(A,P$_A$)}}
child {node (B){IsTrue(A)}
};
\draw[red,very thick] ($(o)!0.5!(A)$) to[bend left=30]  ($(o)!0.5!(B)$);

\begin{scope}[xshift=6.5cm]
\node {Goto(P$_B$)} [grow'=up]
child { node (B) [left=0cm]{ Goto(P$_B$)}
    child {node (sayb) { Say(B,P$_B$)}}
    child {node (istrueb) {IsTrue(B)}}
}
child {node (C)[right=0cm]{ Goto(P$_B$)}
    child {node (sayc)  {Say(C,P$_B$)}}
    child {node (istruec){IsTrue(C)}}
};
\draw[red,very thick] ($(B)!0.5!(sayb)$) to[bend left=30]  ($(B)!0.5!(istrueb)$);
\draw[red,very thick] ($(C)!0.5!(sayc)$) to[bend left=30]  ($(C)!0.5!(istruec)$);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```